# I need to compare one column in 2 csv file and find the missing values and print the missing in new one

Tags: python, pandas, csv

CSV1:

```
Name Gender Sl_no
Abc     f     5
xyx     m     10
hhh     f     20
```

csv2:

```
Sl_no Name Gender 
  10   bla   bla
   5   bla   bla
```

Here I only care about the `sl_no` column, which is in a different index in both the tables and i only need the missing value in cs2 `sl_no`. How do i do this using python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `loc` with `isin`.

```py
import pandas as pd

csv1 = pd.read_csv('path/to/csv1')
csv2 = pd.read_csv('path/to/csv2')

missing = csv1.loc[~csv1['Sl_no'].isin(csv2['Sl_no']), 'Sl_no']
print(missing)
```